# How do I edit stored license headers in KDevelop?

Tags: config, kdevelop

KDevelop can create new files from templates. When creating a new C++ class it is possible to select a license header that will be added to the newly created file.

It also allows to input custom text and then save this for use in future files. I created a new license header and saved it so I can now use it in all my newly created files.

However, I made a typo in the license header and it now shows up every time I create a new file. Is there a way to edit the saved license headers? If not via KDevelop itself, can they be edited on the file system? Where are they stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KDevelop stores license header data in `~/.kde/share/apps/kdevcodegen/licenses/`. Each user created license header is stored as a separate plain text file and can be edited directly.